# IP address in /etc/hosts that will always fail?

Tags: networking, ip, hosts

I know that you can add hostnames to `/etc/hosts` so that resolving them doesn't actually perform a DNS lookup. This would be a line such as

```
123.45.67.89 myhostname
```

My question is, what can I set the first part (IP address) to so that any attempted connection to this `myhostname` will always fail?

**Edit**: By fail, I mean an explicit ICMP rejection if possible. I don't want to wait for a timeout.

### Reason

I have a VM instance running somewhere, sometimes. The cloud server sets a different IP on every launch and I'm not paying for any public domain name. I have a script that launches the instance and adds a line to `/etc/hosts` so I can easily ssh or open a browser tab to this host using `myhostname`.

That all works great, but I'd like to also *remove* this entry when the instance is killed, and have attempted connections to `myhostname` *not* incur any DNS lookups or (worse) try to connect to some same-named host on whatever local domain I'm sitting in at the moment.

Comment: You could set the ip to 127.0.1.1 or anything within 127.0.0.0/8 which will resolve to your local machine.

Comment: In what way would you like the connection to fail? Failure to get any response or an explicit ICMP rejection?

Comment: @TorinCarey An explicit reject packet would be better. I edited the question to say that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want an IP address that a) is guaranteed not to match anything remote and b) will reject everything.

Make one:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -d 127.66.66.66 -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables -I INPUT 2 -i lo -d 127.66.66.66 -j REJECT
```

(or whatever is the equivalent for your iptables firewall management tool of choice.)

Now all TCP connections to 127.66.66.66 will get a TCP RST packet in response, and everything else gets an ICMP rejection. (TCP RST will generally refuse a TCP connection even faster than ICMP, in my experience.)

IP address 127.66.66.66 is within the loopback segment, so it is guaranteed not to interfere with anything non-local.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to have `hosts` force a "not found" response, I think you'd need to have your own DNS server for that. But you could do some other things...

- Use an IP address of `127.0.0.1` (or anything in `127/8`, really) to make the name point to your local host. For a service you're not running, your system would reply with a TCP reset or an error or drop the packet, but if you're running SSH locally, it wouldn't work that well.
- Use any of the private-use addresses, like something in `10/8`. Depending on your configuration, your system may try to send packets to them, but your ISP should drop the packets before they get very far. Or you could just have your firewall reject them before they leave your machine.
- Use something that's practically an invalid address. `0.0.0.1` (or anything in `0/8` except `0.0.0.0`) seems to produce an error on connect in Linux and Windows. `0.0.0.0` is used e.g. DHCP clients before they know their own address, and seems to direct to localhost on Linux. (The whole block is actually reserved to mean "This host on this network".)

Of course all of these are basically lies, and not the cleanest of solutions as such.

Comment: Addresses from the blocks reserved for documentation (RFC 5737) is also a possibility. "The blocks 192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2), and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3) are provided for use in documentation. Addresses within the TEST-NET-1, TEST-NET-2, and TEST-NET-3 blocks SHOULD NOT appear on the public Internet."

Comment: @JohanMyréen, yep, that and a [bunch of other choices](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml), that more or less shouldn't be used. But I'm not sure if they're any "better" than the private-use blocks in that the OS would prevent the packets from leaving the system.

Comment: localhost addresses `127/8` are not ideal, because as you mentioned I will have ssh running on the local machine for example. The local subnets like `10/8` are also not ideal because there could be a machine on the local network with that address.

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to pick an arbitrary IP address (maybe one in `10/8`) at random, then setup a static firewall rule to reject all outgoing traffic to that IP. This breaks if I unluckily pick a legitimate IP that I want to connect to, but the probability of doing that should be negligible. Still feels like a "dirty" solution though.

Comment: @DanRoche, of course you'd pick an address from a block you know your site doesn't use. There's what, 16M addresses in `10/8`, 1M in `172.16/12` and 64k in `192.168/16`. Probably not that many sites that need all of them... :)